# transformer and ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, transformer-model

When I try execute the program below, I found error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class IQR(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): 
    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        self.q1 = X.quantile(0.25)    
        self.q3 = X.quantile(0.75) 
        self.iqr = self.q3 - self.q1
        return self
        
    def transform(self, X, y = None):
        def test_bound(element):
            if element<(self.q1-self.iqr*1.5):
                element = self.q1 - 1.5*self.iqr
            elif element>(self.q3+self.iqr*1.5):
                element=self.q3 + 1.5*self.iqr
            return element
        return X.apply(lambda x : test_bound(x))
```

I wait for the two columns containing data+outliers to be transformed.